# Salesforce DX: Unexpected file found in package .../package.xml

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

For Salesforce DX, after downloading code from an Unmanaged Package to push to a Scratch Org, when I try to convert the unzipped package I am getting an error saying that

```
Unexpected file found in package directory: .../package.xml.
```

I "retrieve" the code from an Unmanaged Packaged in a Sandbox org into a top level directory of my Salesforce DX project called "mdapipkg". I have added this as a path in the sfdx-project.json file. Upon the "convert" command, specifying this directory, I get this error.

I do not understand why it is telling me that the package.xml is unexpected, as it is a typical part of the downloadable zip from an Unmanaged Package.

Has anybody come across this issue?

Answer (score 6):

I came across the solution reading this post: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/07/migrating-existing-projects-salesforce-dx.html.

> Apparently you **cannot delete the .zip before** you convert the files. You have to do it **after.**

Comment: Fwiw, I ran into this problem and it doesn't appear that the order of deletion of the zip affected things. For me, the problem seemed to be that I was trying to run the convert from a place other than the project root.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was with project's configuration file: `sfdx-project.json` and `packageDirectories` attribute.

It looked like this:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    },
    {"path": "mdapipkg"}
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://test.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "42.0"
}
```

I added `mdapipkg` directory to `packageDirectories` because I thought it will help me with some `sfdx force:mdapi` commands but it didn't and caused such problems. It was first complaining about `package.xml` than about `unpackaged.zip` file. Once I removed that folder from `sfdx-project.json` convert command did the work!